# Can RDF Properties contain other properties?

Tags: rdf

Can the RDF:Property contain other properties along with rdf:range and rdf:domain.  For example, could you have the following:

```
<rdf:Property rdf:about="&base;adminStaff">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&base;Staff"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&rdfs;Literal"/>
    <dcterms:description>This is a member of staff</dcterms:description>
</rdf:Property>
```

The bit im interested in here is the use of the dublin core description element.  Is this valid.  It looks ok when viewing it as triples and makes sense but im unsure whether it is valid to have this property inside another property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is valid. You can check it also in the [Dublin Core Metadata Element Set](http://dublincore.org/2008/01/14/dcelements.rdf).

```
<rdf:Property rdf:about="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="en-US">Creator</rdfs:label>
  <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en-US">
    An entity primarily responsible for making the resource.
  </rdfs:comment>
  <dcterms:description xml:lang="en-US">
    Examples of a Creator include a person, an organization, or a service. Typically, the name of a Creator should be used to indicate the entity.
  </dcterms:description>
</rdf:Property>
```